# Using cURL to login in a web page

Tags: shell, post, curl

I'm looking for any way to login in a web page containing this data:

```
--- FORM report. Uses POST to URL "<form name="form1" method="post" >"
Input: NAME="login" (TEXT)
Input: NAME="password" (PASSWORD)
Input: NAME="Submit" VALUE="Continue &raquo;" (IMAGE)
```

Using this cURL command:

```
curl -d "login=john" -d "password=venus123&submit=Continue%20&raquo;" URL
```

I get this output:

```
<h1>The page cannot be displayed</h1>
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.
<hr>
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: Use your web browser's developer's tools and check what it sends when you fill in the form manually. Then mimic exactly that with curl.

Comment: I´m using Firefox HTTPFox, but I can´t catch any username/password data. Unfortunately I still can´t login in that page using cURL.

Comment: Ues Firefox's devtools, then on the exact request you right-click and select "copy as curl" ...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Using chrome´s "Copy as cURL" optins help me much, but I still can´t get the send password part.

Answer (score 1):

It is the issue with urlencoding of data. You need to change your `&` character before the `raquo` with `%26`.

```
curl -d "login=john" -d "password=venus123&submit=Continue%20%26raquo;" URL
                                                             ^^^ here
```

Also if your password contains special characters, that case you have to do urlencoding on them too. You can find online urlencoder free at internet.

Answer (score 1):

You're combining multiple form fields in the password field `"password=venus123&submit=Continue%20&raquo;"`. The part after `&` is another field called `Submit`.

```
curl -d "login=john" -d "password=venus123" --data-urlencode "Submit=Continue &raquo;" URL
```

Note, that I used [--data-urlencode](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-urlencode) instead of `-d` which performs also URL-encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you use Chrome dev. tools or [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) to record `curl` calls. Then it gets easier to use the calls you recorded again.